# Combine data of one sheet from multiple excels

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I have multiple excel files in the following format:

```
ID | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 | User
```

**Data from excel1:**

```
ID | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | User 
1  | test |       |       |       | John
```

**Data from Excel2:**

```
ID | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | User
1  | test |   a   |   b   |       | John
```

**Data from Excel3:**

```
ID | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | User
1  | test |       |       |   c   | John
```

What I want to do is to combine these cells.

**Desired output:**

```
ID | Name | Prop1 | Prop2 | Prop3 | User
1  | test |   a   |   b   |   c   | John
```

If the cell is empty on a file and the other file has value in it, I would like to replace it.

is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want your output to look? 1 single row or multiple rows? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated the question for desired output.

Comment: So some problem in solution? Answer was edited if dont need `reduce` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

        import glob
        glob.glob("C:/your_path_here/*.xlsx")

        all_data = pd.DataFrame()
        for f in glob.glob("C:/your_path_here/*.xlsx"):
            df = pd.read_excel(f)
            all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
            print(all_data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create list of all DataFrames by `glob`, for final `df` need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

```
import glob
from functools import reduce

files = glob.glob('files/*.xlsx')
dfs = [pd.read_excel(fp).set_index(['ID','Name','User']) for fp in files]

df1 = reduce(lambda l,r: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(l,r), dfs)
print (df1)
             Prop1 Prop2 Prop3
ID Name User                  
1  test John     a     b     c
```

EDIT: If dont need combine files with `NaN`s solution is simplier:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('files/*.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fp) for fp in files],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Correct if the file is same , but I think OP mentioned different file names.

Comment: File name is irrelevant here I guess. But I am having trouble installing functools in `Python 2.7.13`.

Comment: @DarthVader - I think it is not necessary install, check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). I think for `2.7` python is necessary only remove `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Excel1.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1');
df2= pd.read_excel('Excel2.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1');
df3 = pd.read_excel('Excel3.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
mylist = [df1,df2,d3]
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ID','USER'])
df = pd.merge(df, df3, on=['ID','USER'])
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I haven't got the chance to test this , but it should work .

Comment: Hey Rehan, can you please look at the question. I need the desired output as above. Not a simple concat.